# specify separate styles for Latin and CJK

Tags: css, cjk

I have an existing CSS file that I want to use with pages that also contain Japanese, but the generated italics don't look good with Kanji, and I definitely need different fonts from the ones used for English.

Is there any way in CSS to specify a font or style for a specific set of glyphs, in this case CJK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by glyphs, but by `lang` attribute, so

```html
<html lang='ja'>
```

```css
body:lang(ja) { font-family: "ＭＳ　Ｐゴシック"; }
i:lang(ja)    { font-style: normal; }
```

The `:lang` selector identifies elements which have the specified `lang` attribute anywhere in their ancestor chain.

Comment: So if I have a string of text like "the character 難 means ...", then I always have to put a span around the 難?

Comment: No, it will pick up the first font that has that glyoh. So put English fonts first, then CJK. Howeve. If you to to define things like italics in a language specific way then yes, you'd have to put it in a span.